# PHP Variable in function options

Tags: php, arrays

I want to use the following FPDF extension to password protect some PDFs

```
function SetProtection($permissions=array(), $user_pass='ABC123', $owner_pass='ABC123!')
```

However I want the $user_pass to be a variable definded above, such as date of birth.
The options I have tried so far include

```
function SetProtection($permissions=array(), $user_pass=''.$dateofbirth, $owner_pass='ABC123!')
function SetProtection($permissions=array(), $user_pass=$dateofbirth, $owner_pass='ABC123!')
function SetProtection($permissions=array(), $user_pass='".$dateofbirth."', $owner_pass='ABC123!')
```

however i'm usually met with the same issue where the password is basically the plain text of anything in the '' and not the variabe, in that final case for example, the password is `".$dateofbirth."` entered exactly like that.

I'm struggling to find the correct syntax.

Comment: Is this php or javascript?  Why is it tagged as javascript?

Comment: You can't evaluate expressions inside function declarations. You're mixing up parameter definition with passing parameters into the function. You should be passing that date of birth into a function call. Maybe go through a tutorial on functions? @Taplar Judging by the concatenation, PHP.

Comment: Aside: having a d.o.b. as a password isn't the best idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use variables as default values. The closest thing you can do to achieve the same effect is to manually check and replace the argument variable, eg,

```
function SetProtection($permissions=array(), $user_pass=null, $owner_pass='ABC123!')
{
    // You can also check if empty string if you have a use-case where empty string
    // would also mean replace with $dateofbirth
    if ($user_pass === null) {
        global $dateofbirth;
        $user_pass = $dateofbirth;
    }

    ...
}
```

```
$SetProtection = function ($permissions=array(), $user_pass=null, $owner_pass='ABC123!') use ($dateofbirth)
{
    // You can also check if empty string if you have a use-case where empty string
    // would also mean replace with $dateofbirth
    if ($user_pass === null) {
        $user_pass = $dateofbirth;
    }

    ...
}
```

```
class SomeClass()
{
    private $dateofbirth;

    ...

    function SetProtection($permissions=array(), $user_pass=null, $owner_pass='ABC123!')
    {
        // You can also check if empty string if you have a use-case where empty string
        // would also mean replace with $dateofbirth
        if ($user_pass === null) {
            $user_pass = $this->dateofbirth;
        }

        ...
    }
```